# Occasional crash when type casting to find Array vs. Dictionary in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to resolve an infrequent crashlytics report for an app in market.

Report says EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS when doing what appears to be a normal type casting:

`if let responseArray = response as? [[String: AnyObject]]`

See the offending code on line 11 of the code snippet below.

Any clue why this crash could occur here?  I cannot seem to reproduce it with simulator or attached device.

```
func callingFunction() {
    if var response: AnyObject = aFunction {  //aFunction returns AnyObject?
        if let response = response as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
            someFunction(response)
        }
    }
}

func someFunction(response: AnyObject) {
    var responses = [[String: AnyObject]]()
    if let responseArray = response as? [[String: AnyObject]] {  // Crashes here - sometimes
        responses = responseArray
    } else if let responseDictionary = response as? [String: AnyObject] {
        responses.append(responseDictionary)
    } else {
        assertionFailure("Response has unexpected type, response:\(response)")
    }
    // Do a other stuff
}
```

Is there a better way to determine if an received object is an array or a dictionary?

Comment: If you've solved your own problem, don't edit the question — instead, post your own answer to the question (as seen in [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)). This helps people find it better later.

Comment: Thanks rickster - I moved it to the answer section.

Answer (score 1):

I neglected to point out that the crash on the code above was happening on a background thread.  I originally, and perhaps mistakenly ruled out a thread contention issue because the crash report contained no other access to this code on any other thread.

But it turns out that wrapping the entire function in an "obj_sync" solved the problem.  Like this...

```
func someFunction(response: AnyObject) {
    objc_sync_enter(self)
    // Do the same code as above
    objc_sync_exit(self)
}
```

Also, might be helpful to others to point out a failed attempt to solve the problem.  I replaced...

```
if let responseArray = response as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
    responses = responseArray
}
```

with...

```
if response is Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>> {
    responses = response as! [[String : AnyObject]]
}
```

...but it still crashed in the same place.